# FB.Init fails trying to convert Int32 to Char

Tags: c#, json, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

The Facebook API works when it's in the Unity Editor but not on the Facebook Canvas.  I receive this error in the development console:

```
>OverflowException: Value is greater than Char.MaxValue or less than Char.MinValue
>>System.Convert.ToChar(Int32 value)
>>Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.get_PeekChar()
>>Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.EatWhitespace()
>>Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.get_NextToken()
>>Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.ParseValue()
>>Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.Parse(System.String jsonString)
>>Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(System.String json)
>>Facebook.NativeDialog.CommonVariablesCallback(.FBResult result)
>>Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogPost.CallbackWithErrorHandling(.FBResult result)
>>Facebook.AsyncRequestString+<Start>.c_Iterator0.MoveNext()
```

I understand that converting an Int32 into a Char, which contains 1Byte, is not possible but I've not included any such conversions in my code related to to the Facebook API.

I've found out from successive deletions that it occurs in the method FB.Init
My code is very simple:

```
FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
```

Where OnInitComplete and OnHideUnity just call Debug.Log.

If anybody has found a reason or solution I'd very much like to know.

Edit:  I'm using Facebook SDK 6.2.1, build version 150128.46cb09fefe856ca and Unity 5.

Comment: Is there perhaps any in initialization code, where your app id is used – and that app id is given as an integer value? If so, try passing it as a string instead.

Comment: Well I've been checking the SDK Initialisation and I can't see any treatment of the appId being used as an integer, only a string.  I even changed the form of FB.Init to include the appId as such:FB.Init(OnInitComplete, "1234564789", true, true, true, false, true, OnHideUnity, null);

Comment: In c#, [char](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) is 2 unsigned bytes not one byte, so `char.MinValue` is `0` and `char.MaxValue` is `65535`.

Comment: Assuming that `Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize` has the same code as is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710), then `MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize("")` will throw exactly this exception because `StringReader.Peek()` returns `-1` for an empty string.  Check to make sure your string isn't empty -- it may be so because of the different build environment.